# Python Scipy Curvefit to Linear Quadratic Curve

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a linear quadratic model curve to experiment data.  The Y axis values reduce from 1 to 10^-5.  When I use the following code, the resulting curve often seems to not fit the data at higher X values.  I have a suspicion that because the Y values at high X values are so small, the resulting difference between the experiment value and model value is small.  But I would like the model curve to pass as close to the higher X value points as possible (even if it means the low values are not as well fitted).  I haven't found anything about weighting in scipy.optimize.curve_fit, other than using standard deviations (which I don't have).  How can I improve my model fit at high X values?

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def lq(x, a, b):
    #y(x) = exp[-(ax+bx²)]
    y = []
    for i in x:
        x2=i**2
        ax = a*i
        bx2 = b*x2
        y.append(np.exp(-(ax+bx2)))
    return y
#x and y are from experiment
x=[0,1.778,2.921,3.302,6.317,9.524,10.54]
y=[1,0.831763771,0.598411595,0.656145266,0.207014135,0.016218101,0.004102041]
(a,b), pcov = curve_fit(lq, x, y, p0=[0.05,0.05])
#make the model curve using a and b
xmodel = list(range(0,20))
ymodel = lq(xmodel, a, b)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.plot(x,y, "ro", label="Experiment")  
ax1.plot(xmodel,ymodel, "r--", label="Model")  
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your assessment that the fit is not very sensitive to small misfits for the small values of `y`.  Since you are plotting the data and fit on a semi-log plot, I think that what you really want is to fit in the log-space as well.  That is, you could fit `log(y)` to a quadratic function.  As an aside (but an important one if you're going to be doing numerical work with Python), you should not loop over lists but rather use `numpy` arrays: this will make everything faster and simpler.  With such changes, your script might look like

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def lq(x, a, b):
    return -(a*x+b*x*x)

x = np.array([0,1.778,2.921,3.302,6.317,9.524,10.54])
y = np.array([1,0.831763771,0.598411595,0.656145266,0.207014135,0.016218101,0.004102041])

(a,b), pcov = curve_fit(lq, x, np.log(y), p0=[0.05,0.05])

xmodel = np.arange(20)             # Note: use numpy!
ymodel = np.exp(lq(xmodel, a, b))  # Note: take exp() as inverse log()
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.plot(x, y, "ro", label="Experiment")
ax1.plot(xmodel,ymodel, "r--", label="Model")
plt.show()
```

Note that the model function is changed to just be the `ax+bx^2` you wanted to write in the first place and that this is now fitting `np.log(y)`, not `y`. This will give a much more satisfying fit at the smaller `y` values.

You might also find `lmfit` (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) helpful for this problem (disclaimer: I am a lead author).  With this, your fit script could become

```
from lmfit import Model
model = Model(lq)
params = model.make_params(a=0.05, b=0.05)
result = model.fit(np.log(y), params, x=x)

print(result.fit_report())

xmodel = np.arange(20)
ymodel = np.exp(result.eval(x=xmodel))

plt.plot(x, y, "ro", label="Experiment")
plt.plot(xmodel, ymodel, "r--", label="Model")
plt.yscale('log')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This will print out a report including fit statistics and interpretable uncertainties and correlations between variables:

```
[[Model]]
    Model(lq)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 7
    # data points      = 7
    # variables        = 2
    chi-square         = 0.16149397
    reduced chi-square = 0.03229879
    Akaike info crit   = -22.3843833
    Bayesian info crit = -22.4925630
[[Variables]]
    a: -0.05212688 +/- 0.04406602 (84.54%) (init = 0.05)
    b:  0.05274458 +/- 0.00479056 (9.08%) (init = 0.05)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(a, b) = -0.968
```

and give a plot of

[image]

Note that `lmfit` Parameters can be fixed or bounded and that lmfit comes with many built-in models.

Finally, if you were to include a constant term in the quadratic model, you would not really need an iterative method but could use polynomial regression, as with `numpy.polyfit`.

Comment: I like that your LMFit provides the stats so readily.  Your curve_fit solution - take the exp of the function - seems like something I should have tried, but I thought curve_fit worked differently to how it actually works and so I didn't even try :(  My bad...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a graphical Python fitter using your data with a Gompertz type of sigmoidal equation. This code uses scipy's Differential Evolution genetic algorithm module to determine initial parameter estimates for scipy's non-linear curve_fit() routine. That scipy module uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space, requiring bounds within which to search. In this example, I made all of the parameter search bounds from -2.0 to 2.0, and that seems to work in this case. Note that it is much easier to provide *ranges* for the initial parameter estimates than specific values, and those parameter ranges can be generous.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings

#x and y are from experiment
x=[0,1.778,2.921,3.302,6.317,9.524,10.54]
y=[1,0.831763771,0.598411595,0.656145266,0.207014135,0.016218101,0.004102041]

# alias data to match previous example code
xData = numpy.array(x, dtype=float)
yData = numpy.array(y, dtype=float)


def func(x, a, b, c): # Sigmoidal Gompertz C from zunzun.com
    return a * numpy.exp(b * numpy.exp(c*x))


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([-2.0, 2.0]) # search bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([-2.0, 2.0]) # search bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([-2.0, 2.0]) # search bounds for c

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# now call curve_fit without passing bounds from the genetic algorithm,
# just in case the best fit parameters are aoutside those bounds
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # plot wuth log Y axis scaling
    plt.yscale('log')

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it needs to be the linear quadratic model that is being fitted.  I can manually plot values of a and b to get the data to fit, so I know the solutions exist, but I need a programmatic way to do it.  I've edited the question to be clearer.

Comment: As a test, if you use those specific values as the initial parameter estimates for curve_fit does it work well? That test result would mean that you only need code to find better initial parameter estimates, and then you are done.

Comment: No, it comes up with essentially the same fit as using initial estimates of 0.1 for both values.